# How to add to arraylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, arraylist

I am using javascript for my server side validation.I need to add all data from a table which is dynamically generated while clicking an add button.

Clicking ADD button section is working fine.Also i added date picker to 2nd and 3rd columns.its working fine.The code is given below.....

```
             function addRow(tableId) { //Add new row to given table having id tableId
var table = document.getElementById(tableId);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="code'+ rowCount +'" name="code" maxlength="16"/>';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="datepicker2'+ rowCount +'" class="datepicker" name="validFrom" maxlength="50" >';
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="datepicker3'+ rowCount +'" class="datepicker" name="validFrom" maxlength="50" >';
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="del'+ rowCount +'" name="del" />';
```

Html code

```
<div class="systemsettings">
            <h3><spring:message code="systemSetting.ratePeriods.label"/></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="systemset" >
            <!-- table table-hover table-striped  table-bordered table-highlight-head-->
            <table  id="systemsettingstid" class="table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead class="tax_thead" id="tdDetailList">
                <tr >
                    <!-- <th>Applicable From</th> -->
                    <th width="200" id="code" title="Code"  >Code</th>
                    <th width="200" id="from" title="from ">from</th>
                    <th width="200" id="to" title="to">to</th>
                    <th width="50" id="del" title="del">del</th>

                <!--    <th width="45" ><div class="add_new">

            <a href="javascript:addRow('taxHdrTableList');" title="Add New Row"></a>
            </div></th> -->
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody></tbody>
            </table>


            </div>

             <div>
              <tr>
              <button type="button"  onClick="javascript:addRow('systemsettingstid');">Add</button>
              </tr>
            </div>
```

**DELETE BUTTON:**

I have a delete button also appended inside the html code.
While clicking it the corresponding row should be deleted(fixed automatically while clicking add button on every row).

**MY PROBLEM:**

Adding and delete does not affect back end it just need to alter in an arraylist.

During final form submission the arraylist needs  to go to backend(built in spring mvc).

1) Can we create an arraylist in javascript?

2) If we can how to add the text boxes and date picker details into arraylist?.

4) How to pass that arraylist in to my spring mvc controller?

NB:I am new to javascript.Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus he's using Java for the back end. (spring)

Comment: @UnknownOctopus:Java is my backend and spring mvc is the frame work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script>
    var tdDetailList = [];
    function init() {
        var tdDetailTable = document.getElementById("tdDetailTable");       
        for (var i = 0, row; row = tdDetailTable.rows[i]; i++) {
            var tdDetail = {code : row.cells[0].innerHTML, datepicker2 : row.cells[1].innerHTML, datepicker3 : row.cells[2].innerHTML};         
            tdDetailList.push(tdDetail);
        }
        alert(getDetailTableJson());
    }

    function deleteRow(index){
       tdDetailList.splice(index, 1);
       var tdDetailTable = document.getElementById("tdDetailTable");
       tdDetailTable.deleteRow(index);
       alert(getDetailTableJson());
    }

    function getDetailTableJson(){
        return JSON.stringify(tdDetailList);
    }
</script>

<body onload="init();">
<table id="tdDetailTable">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(0); return true;">del</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(1); return true;">del</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**Can we create an arraylist in javascript?**

Yes. In my example `var tdDetailList = [];` is array (list).

You can add elements to it: 
`tdDetailList.push(tdDetail);`

and remove element in index: `tdDetailList.splice(index, 1);`

**If we can how to add the text boxes and date picker details into arraylist?.**

You can create object like:

```
var tdDetail = {code : row.cells[0].innerHTML, datepicker2 : row.cells[1].innerHTML, datepicker3 : row.cells[2].innerHTML};
```

with fields of your table and add the object to your list.

**How to pass that arraylist in to my spring mvc controller?**

Convert the list to json

```
JSON.stringify(tdDetailList);
```

In my example: "[{"code":"1","datepicker2":"2","datepicker3":"3"},{"code":"4","datepicker2":"5","datepicker3":"6"}]"

and send.

Comment: clear explanation of concepts.helps me a lot.thanku @Vitaly

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept my answer to finish this topic.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to add and delete using JAVA SCRIPT then  it will very complex and lengthy.

But using JQUERY it will work fine and easily you can handle ADD, DELETE actions also

use JQUERY and in this append and remove methods are there you can use it and insert a row in table and delete a row in table

May be you new in jQUERY but once you get it, its amazing than JAVA SCRIPT

Hope you getting let me know if you have any confusion. ['}